# D3.js scale returning wrong values from dataset

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm having a problem with `scales` in d3.js. As I type the min and max into the Firefox console, I get the max value as the min and the second-max value as the max. What's the problem here?

Here is my dataset in form of csv file:

```
word,occur
obama,11
theguardian,9
world, 8
state, 8
care, 7
pakistan,7
block, 6
blog, 6
healthcare, 5
```

here is what I type into the console and the values I get in return:

```
    d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.occur}); => "11"
    d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.occur}); = "9"
```

the d3.max should return me 11 and d3.min should return me 5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are probably not converting your data from a `string` to a `number`. The following should give you the correct answer:

```
d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return +d.occur}); 
d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return +d.occur});
```

However, you probably want to convert the `occur` column of your data to numeric right after reading it:

```
d3.csv('myfile', function (err, dataset) {     
    dataset.forEach(function (d) { d.occur = +d.occur; });
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Very straightforward.  Always forget about the +.

Comment: #"%#$ &#$% strings... (triple facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

For people who are not using CSV files, but may be graphing a JSON dataset, you can use `parseInt` in your accessor definition.

for example

```
yAccessor = (d) => parseInt(d.occur);
```