# Height of bars too large

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am implementing d3 charts but bars of my chart are crossing the y axis means they are going out of my canvas.It seems like height is the problem. Dont know the reason.I have scale of y axis till 500 if any values is grater than 500 then that goes out of my canvas. But the scale are made by d3. So i cant manipulate the scale.This is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <title>D3</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css" /> -->

    <style>
        body {
            color: #000;
        }

        .axis {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .bar {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .bar:hover {
            fill: brown;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="123.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
 var thisIsGlobal;
 </script>

</head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<div align="center">
    From : <input type="date" name="field1" id="field1" /> To : <input type="date" name="field2" id="field2" /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="render(true)" value="Submit" />
</div>

<script>
    var jsonURL = 'avb.json';

    var myData = [];
    var fliterdata=[];
    var tempdata=[];
    var selectop="";

function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
   var result = [];
  for (var foo in json) {

    if (json[foo][key] == value) {
      result.push(json[foo]);


    }
  }
  return result;
}

function selectValue(d){
   // console.log("before op",selectop );
  switch(selectop){
            case "01":
                return d.val001;
                break;
            case "02":
                return d.val002;
                break;
            case "03":
                return d.val003;
                break;
            case "04":
                return d.val004;
                break;
            case "05":
                return d.val005;
                break;
            default:
                //console.log("default");
                return d.val001;
        }


 }

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 80,
        left: 40
    };
    var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
    var vAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
    var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
            .style('padding', '5 15px')
            .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
            .style('border-radius', '5px')
            .style('opacity', 'o');

//function getDates() {
  //      return [document.getElementById('field1').value, document.getElementById('field2').value];
  //  }

    function render(filterByDates) {


        d3.select('svg').remove();

        if (filterByDates) {

                tempData=fliterdata;
                console.log("before date fliter data", tempData);
            var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('field1').value);
            var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('field2').value);

            //date1 = new Date(date1 + " UTC");
            //date2 = new Date(date2 + " UTC");

            //date1 = new Date( date1.getTime() + (date1.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
            //date2 = new Date( date2.getTime() + (date2.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));


            tempData = tempData.filter(function(d) {
                console.log(date1,date2);
              //  alert(date1);
                return d.date >= date1 && d.date <= date2;


            });
                console.log("After date fliter data", tempData);
        }


        xScale.domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
                    return d.date;
                }).sort(function(a,b) {
                  return a > b;
                })
        );

        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {
                //console.log("selectValue(d)"  , selectValue(d));
                //var cool=d.val00+selectop;
                //console.log("cool",cool);
            return selectValue(d);
        })]);

        var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
               .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
               .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
               .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg


                .append('g')
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(hAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

        svg
                .append('g')
                .attr("class", "yaxis")
                .call(vAxis)

        svg
                .selectAll(".bar") //makes bar
                .data(tempData)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .style("fill", "teal")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.date);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) {


                    return yScale(selectValue(d));
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {

                    console.log("as", d.value);
                    return height - yScale(selectValue(d));
                })
                .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                            .style('opacity', 1)

                    tooltip.html(d.value)
                            .style('left', (d3.event.pageX) + 'px')
                            .style('top', (d3.event.pagey) + 'px')
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)
                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                            .style('opacity', 0)
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
                });
    }

    d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {

        myData = data;
        myData.forEach(function(d) {

            d.date = new Date(d.date);
            d.value="";

            d.name = +d.name;
            console.log(d.date,"Gt date");
            d.date = new Date(d.date + " UTC");
            console.log(d.date,"localtimezone date");
        });

        //myData.data.sort();
        //console.log(,"hello j");

        //render(false,myData);
       // console.log(render);
        //copy from here 

        //tempData=myData;


         $("#listbox").on("click", function() {




            var key = $(this).val();

            var value=$('#listbox option:selected').text();
            console.log("tx:", value);

            selectop=String(key);
            selectop=selectop.slice(-2);
             console.log("mydata: ", myData);
             console.log("prod:",selectop );

            fliterdata=filterJSON(myData, key, value);

            console.log("fliterdata: ", fliterdata);
            tempData=fliterdata;
                    render(false);




        });

        //till here
    });
</script>

<label> List of Tables : </label><br>
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <div style="height: 30px; width: 50px;">
        <select id="dropdown1"></select>
    </div>
    <style>
        #listbox {
            display: none;
        }
        #listbox {
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>

    <div style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: -30px; height: auto;">
        <select id="listbox", multiple></select>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "avb.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(obj) {
                console.log("obj--", obj)
                var jsObject = obj;
                var usedNames = [];
                $('<option>', {
                    text: 'Select your Option',
                    value: '',
                    selected: 'selected',
                    disabled: 'disabled',
                    location: 'fixed'
                }).appendTo('#dropdown1')
                $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                    if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1)  {

                        $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                        usedNames.push(value.name);
                        }

                });
                $('#dropdown1').change(function() {

                    $('#listbox').toggle(this.value != "");




                });

       $('#dropdown1').change(function() {

                    $('#listbox').empty();

                    $('<option>', {
                        text: 'Select your List Option',
                        value: '',
                        selected: 'selected',
                        disabled: 'disabled'
                    }).appendTo('#listbox');


                    var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                    console.log("as".selection);
                    $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                        console.log("%o",value)
                        if (value['name'] == selection) {
                            var optionHtml = '';
                            for (var i = 1; i <=20; i++) {
                                var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                                var val = 'val' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                                //optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '" data-val="'+value[val]+'">' + value[attr] + '</option>';

                                if(value[val]){ optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '" data-val="'+value[val]+'">' + value[attr] + '</option>';  }


                            }

                            $("#listbox").css("width", "500px")

                            $("#listbox").css("height", "300px")
                            $('#listbox').append(optionHtml);
                            return false;
                        }
                        var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
                        console.log(selectedOption);

                    });

                });
 }
    });
});
```

My json

```
[ {
 "name": "ABC",
 "date": 1459461600000, 
"attr001": "SIGN1",
 "val001": "7", 
"attr002": "SIGN2",
 "val002": "7",
 "attr003": "SIGN3", 
"val003": "100.00", 
"attr004": "SIGN4", 
"val004": "0" 
}, 
{
"name": "ABC",
 "date": 1459461600000,
 "attr001": "SIGN1",
 "val001": "20", 
"attr002": "SIGN2", 
"val002": "70", 
"attr003": "SIGN3", 
"val003": "100.00",
 "attr004": "SIGN4",
 "val004": "50" 
 }, 


 { "name": "XYZ", 
"date": 1459125900000, 
"attr001": "VISSE1",
 "val001": "100", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "7",
 "attr003": "VISSE3",
 "val003": "300.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "0"
 },

 { "name": "XYZ",
 "date": 1459461600000,
 "attr001": "VISSE1", 
"val001": "50", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "70",
 "attr003": "VISSE3",
 "val003": "300.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "0" },

{ "name": "XYZ", 
"date": 1459461900000, 
"attr001": "VISSE1",
"val001": "300", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "10", 
"attr003": "VISSE3", 
"val003": "500.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "0" } ]
```

Comment: Can you put your example on jsfiddle?

Comment: this is my fiddle but in this chrt is not getting rendered ..dont know why

Comment: could either link to a hosted version on jsfiddle/codepen/etc or provide the relative files too `123.js` and `avb.json`

Comment: this isnt your fiddle as you dont show your data so obviously it wont run. Add your data and we can take a look

Comment: Please have a look above i have added mu js and json

Comment: Here is your fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/ru2y41Lo/. Whereas on another question i helped you with this was it : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/k013yrgc/. You make this so much harder for yourself by not creating a working fiddle. I'm not going to more effort to make your code work before even attempting to answer your question. Have a working example before asking a question. You won't get answers otherwise !!!!!!

Comment: :jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/k013yrgc.  this is the fiddle in which u can see my bars going out of the canvas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3.js scale returning wrong values from dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592782/d3-js-scale-returning-wrong-values-from-dataset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was your `d3.max` function wasn't returning the correct value. So instead of this :

```
d3.max(myData, function(d) {
   console.log(d.val001)
     return d.val001;
   })
```

Do this :

```
d3.max(myData, function(d) {
   console.log(d.val001)
     return +d.val001; //this is the change
   })
```

This is due to your function not converting your string to an integer.

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/k013yrgc/14/

Comment: I have changed in my code here  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {           return selectValue(+d);           but now my chart is not getting displayed

Comment: what is 'selectValue' ?

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do with `return selectValue(+d); `

Comment: You need to do this `return +selectValue( "01");`  and its better to return just value i.e. `val001` than `d.val001` I think you can figure out the rest.

Comment: hi..now its woking but now at y scale a dot and then comma is coming before number like this .,400 like this   to represent 1400 and .,800 to represnt 1800

Comment: This works perfectly with the fiddle you (which I sorted) provided. It solved the problem. I have explained your problem and why it occurs. Use common sense to work it out. The reason why you're getting '.,' before the 400 is because its there in the data or you have added it yourself !